# How can I use LINQ to retrieve entries that contain a specific property of a list within a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of `IJapaneseDictionaryEntry` objects which are described below.  Inside this are `IKanji` objects that contain `Priorites` objects.

I have a rather difficult thing I would like to do and would appreciate any advice / suggestions. What I would like to do is to retrieve entries that have an entry that have  `Priority` of "Frequency3" from the list `entries` that I created.

```
public interface IJapaneseDictionaryEntry
{
    int Sequence { get; }
    IEnumerable<IKanji> Kanjis { get; }
    IEnumerable<IReading> Readings { get; }
    IEnumerable<ISense> Senses { get; }
}
```

Where each object contains a list of `IKanji` objects

```
public interface IKanji
{
    string Text { get; }
    IEnumerable<KanjiInformation> Informations { get; }
    IEnumerable<Priority> Priorities { get; }
}
```

Here's the list:

```
List<IJapaneseDictionaryEntry> entries = dictionary.GetEntries().ToList();
```

Here's a view that I think might help explain the contents:

[image]

I hope the information here is enough as it seems difficult to explain what I need to retrieve.

Comment: what is the problem you're facing? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return any entry which has at least 1 `Kanjis` that its priorities contain Frequency3:

```
var result = entries.Where(e => e.Kanjis.Any(k => k.Priorities.Contains(Priority.Frequency3))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why you have this as ToArray(), instead of ToList(). Could I change to ToList() if I wanted and is there an advantage to one or the other?

Comment: @Alan2 Of course, I didn't know whether you need an array or a list, you can change it to list. and you are welcome.

Comment: I just realized I have a similar question so will post that now.  Hope the answer for that one can also be done with LINQ.

Comment: I'm just checking your questions

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
entries.Select(c => c.Kanjis.Where(x => x.Priorities.Contains(Priority.Frequency3)));
```

Comment: This does answer the question.